# usort array of values putting indexes with no value at the bottom

Tags: php, date, sorting, usort

I am using usort to sort my arrays. I have an array that contains warranty dates. And a sort function that sorts it. However the problem I am having is that not all of the items in the array have a warranty. I want to sort the array but always placing the ones with no date at the bottom.

```
function warrantyA($a, $b){
    if($a->Warranty == "Available" and $b->Warranty == "Available"){
        $a = explode('/', $a->WarrantyDescription);
        $b = explode('/', $b->WarrantyDescription);

        $today = date("d-m-Y");

        $diffa = abs(strtotime($a[0]) - strtotime($today));
        $diffb = abs(strtotime($b[0]) - strtotime($today));

        $a = floor($diffa / 86400 / 30 );
        $b =  floor($diffb / 86400 / 30 );
        return $a - $b;
    }
}
```

The above is the code I have now.It does not work the way I want it to. Each object has warranty and warranty description. If there is a warranty then it will say "Avaiable".

The code take the warranty and compares it to today's date to determine the amount of months left on the warranty and I want to sort it by that number.

How can I make this functional so that any item that has no warranty is placed at the bottom of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bit of a trick: Turn the results of `$a->Warranty=="Available"` and `$b->Warranty == "Available"` into ints ( will be zero or one), then do a similar subtraction to what you have. If a has a warranty and b doesn't, this will be 1 - 0, or a is greater. If a does not but b does, it will return -1, and 0 if they both don't.

```
$a_has = (int) $a->Warranty == "Available";
$b_has = (int) $b->Warranty == "Available";
if($a_has and $b_has){
    // keep your code here
}

return $a_has - $b_has;
```

Comment: Intresting. I will try this out and let you know if it works for me. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Ok this worked when I sort In descending order! Thank you! Do you have any tricks for ascending? As in display shortest warranty first ascending to the longest and then displaying those without any? Whats happening now is its displaying the ones with no warranty first.

Comment: Swap the two terms in the last expression, that should move them to the opposite end of the results. Then the sorting of the ones with warranties is all in your code.